# Ошибка с подключением string

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

Вот тут собственно ошибка в чем проблема? я не могу понять бред какой-то. В stdafx.h я тоже include но мало того что не видит string так ещё и ошибки переопределения какого то выбивает, очень странное поведение подскажите пжлст)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а string чей??? std ???

Comment: А где std::? Строка объявлена в пространстве имен std.

Comment: Парни спасибо мне иногда кажется что я идиот,  и делаю детские ошибки из-за того что жизнь не дает мне спокойно сконцентрироватся на программировании

Comment: И еще - в следующий раз задавайте вопрос текстом, а не картинкой...

Comment: Вверху есть текст,  смотри внимательно

Comment: @OlexiePolishchyk, имелось ввиду, что код надо выкладывать как код, а не снимками экрана

Answer (score 1):

Класс `string` находится в пространстве имён `std`, а не глобальном, как пытался использовать в коде. Необходимо заменить `string` на `std::string`.